# Homotopy between homeomorphism and the identity

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $h\colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ a homeomorphism, and $I \colon [0,1]\to[0,1]$ the identity. I want show a homotopy $H:h \sim I$. I want show it in order to show that parametrization of a path is homotopic to that path, but I couldn't explicit it.

> We say that $f\colon X \to Y$ and $g\colon X \to Y$ are homotopic if there's a continuous map $H\colon X\times[0,1] \to Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$. We call $H$ of homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

Comment: "to explicit" isn't really used in English...boo!! We have to say something clunky like "to make explicit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard homotopy when your functional values can be added to each other and multiplied by real numbers is the straight-line homotopy:
$$
\begin{align}
H:[0,1]\times[0,1]&\to [0,1]\\
(x,t)&\mapsto (1-t)\cdot h(x)+t\cdot I(x)
\end{align}
$$
It doesn't *always* work, but it works often enough that you should know it and it should almost always be the first thing you try, in my opinion.

Note that if $h(0)=1$ and $h(1)=0$ (i.e. if $h$ is *orientation reversing*) then you are better off using the reversed $I$ as well, given by $x\mapsto 1-t$. The homotopy $H$ will behave nicer in that case.

Comment: @MemeP It works whenever all straight line segments between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain is contained in the codomain (straight line segments is something that needs to make sense, as well, which is not always). This is, of course, always true when the codomain is convex, but it also works, for instance, when constructing a null homotopy of the identity on a star-shaped region of the plane.